# QGIS Fieldtypes Boolean

Tags: database, qgis, fieldtype

is it possible in QGIS to create an column in the attribute table as the fieldtype: boolean?

If someone get a attributetable structure with a fieldtype like boolean, how
u can work with it inside QGIS with this column.

Could QGIS handle boolean or is there a transformation of the field type?